# Unable to integrate custom script extension for windows in ARM template

Tags: azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template

I have simple template with custom script extension that is working fine with blob storage as long as the blob storage is public and can be accessed anonymously. However I am trying add more security to the process by introducing managed identity so the blob can be accessed securely.
[Azure DOCs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/extensions/custom-script-windows) is showing how to create a simple custom script using Managed Identity, however I have been testing it for 3 days and I can't make it work.
Here is what I have done:

1. I have created the User Assigned Identity and assigned it contributor rights to the designated Storage Account
2. I modified the ARM template to grant the VM access to that storage account  using the  User Assigned Identity
3. I modified the Custom Script Extension to introduce the User Assigned Identity in the protected settings section

Now, When deploy the template it times out while provisioning the extension.

Here is what I have in the template for the extension part:

```
      "apiVersion": "2018-06-01",
      "type": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/extensions",
      "name": "[concat(variables('VMSHName'),'/', variables('vmExtensionName'))]",
      "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "dependsOn": [
          "[concat('Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/',variables('VMSHName'))]"
      ],
      "properties": {
          "publisher": "Microsoft.Compute",
          "type": "CustomScriptExtension",
          "typeHandlerVersion": "1.4",
          "settings": {
                       "fileUris": [ "https://xyz.blob.core.windows.net/scripts/Init.ps1" ], 
                       "commandToExecute": "powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -File Init.ps1"
            },
           "protectedSettings": {
                       
                         "managedIdentity" : { "clientId": "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx" }
        }
```

Here is the full template:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {

     
      "AdminUsername": {
          "type": "string",
          "metadata": {
              "description": "Username for local Admin"
          }
      },
      "adminpassword": {
          "type": "securestring",
          "metadata": {
              "description": "Admin password to use"
          }
      }
  },
  "variables": {
      "Environment": "pp",
      "WindowsOSVersion": "2016-Datacenter",
      "storageAccountName": "[concat (resourcegroup().name,variables('Environment'),'stvm')]", 
      "imagePublisher": "MicrosoftWindowsServer",
      "imageOffer": "Windowsserver",
      "storageAccountType": "Standard_LRS",
      "VMSHName": "[concat(resourcegroup().name,'-',variables('Environment'),'-','sh')]",
      "SHNicName":"[concat(variables('VMSHName'),'-','nic')]",
      "VMSizeSH": "Standard_B4ms",
      "virtualNetworkName": "/Infrastructure/InfraVNet",
      "vmExtensionName": "MyExtension",
      "vnetID": "/subscriptions/xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx/resourceGroups/Infra/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/InfraVNet",
      "subnetRef": "[concat(variables('vnetID'),'/subnets/',variables('subnetName'))]",
      "subnetName": "[concat(resourceGroup().name,'subnet')]",
      "ManagedID" : "/subscriptions/xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx/resourceGroups/XXX/providers/Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/userAssignedIdentities/armdeployments"
      
      
      
  },
  "resources": [
      {
          "type": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts",
          "name": "[variables('storageAccountName')]",
          "apiVersion": "2017-06-01",
          "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
          "sku": {
              "name": "[variables('storageAccountType')]"
          },
          "kind": "Storage",
          "properties": {}
      },
      

      {
          "apiVersion": "2018-06-01",
          "type": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines",
          "name": "[variables('VMSHName')]",
          "dependsOn": [
              "[variables('shnicName')]"
            ],
          "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
          "identity": {
             "type": "userAssigned",
             "userAssignedIdentities": { 
                 "[variables('ManagedID')]": {}            
              }
          },
          "properties": {
            "hardwareProfile": {
              "vmSize": "[variables('VMSizeSH')]"
            },
            "osProfile": {
              "computerName":  "[variables('VMSHName')]",
              "adminUsername": "[parameters('adminUsername')]",
              "adminPassword": "[parameters('adminPassword')]"
            },
            "storageProfile": {
              "imageReference": {
                "publisher": "[variables('imagePublisher')]",
                "offer": "[variables('imageOffer')]",
                "sku": "[variables('WindowsOSVersion')]",
                "version": "latest"
              },
              "osDisk": {
                "createOption": "FromImage"
              },
              "dataDisks": [
                {
                  "diskSizeGB": "64",
                  "lun": 0,
                  "createOption": "Empty"
                }
              ]
            },
            "networkProfile": {
              "networkInterfaces": [
                {
                  "id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces',variables('shnicName'))]"
                 }
              ]
            },
            "diagnosticsProfile": {
              "bootDiagnostics": {
                "enabled": "True",
                "storageUri": "[concat(reference(concat('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/', variables('storageAccountName')), '2016-01-01').primaryEndpoints.blob)]"
              }
            }
          }
        },
      
        {
          "apiVersion": "2017-06-01",
          "type": "Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces",
          "name": "[variables('shnicName')]",
          "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
          "properties": {
            "ipConfigurations": [
              {
                "name": "ipconfig1",
                "properties": {
                  "privateIPAllocationMethod": "Dynamic",
                  "subnet": {
                    "id": "[variables('subnetRef')]"
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "apiVersion": "2018-06-01",
          "type": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/extensions",
          "name": "[concat(variables('VMSHName'),'/', variables('vmExtensionName'))]",
          "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
          "dependsOn": [
              "[concat('Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/',variables('VMSHName'))]"
          ],
          "properties": {
              "publisher": "Microsoft.Compute",
              "type": "CustomScriptExtension",
              "typeHandlerVersion": "1.4",
              "settings": {
                           "fileUris": [ "https://xyz.blob.core.windows.net/scripts/Init.ps1" ], 
                           "commandToExecute": "powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -File Init.ps1"
                },
               "protectedSettings": {
                           
                             "managedIdentity" : { "clientId": "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx" }
            }
          }
        }
    ],
  "outputs": {

  }
}
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: {
    "status": "Failed",
    "error": {
        "code": "VMExtensionProvisioningTimeout",
        "message": "Provisioning of VM extension FinovaExtension has timed out. Extension provisioning has taken too long to complete. The extension did not report a message. More information on troubleshooting is available at https://aka.ms/VMExtensionCSEWindowsTroubleshoot"
    }
}

Comment: It times out after 1:30 min as per documentation

Comment: That suggests a problem in the script - you can check vm logs but it sounds like the script is downloaded successfully (otherwise it would be a different error) but the problem is in execution.

Comment: I don't think so, because::
1. The same script works if i make the Blob folder Public
2. The script is not downloaded on the VM
3. The 0.Stats File under the folder "C:\Packages\Plugins\Microsoft.Compute.CustomScriptExtension\1.4\Status" is showing that the actual status is Transitioning, here is the content of the 0.Status file:
"
[{"version":1,"timestampUTC":"2021-08-27T16:34:21.8838915Z","status":{"name":"Microsoft.Compute.CustomScriptExtension","operation":"Enabling Handler","status":"Transitioning","formattedMessage":{"lang":"en-US","message":"Enabling Handler"}}}] "

Comment: Check the handler logs at: C:\WindowsAzure\Logs\Plugins\Microsoft.Compute.CustomScriptExtension - you should be able to see if the script is downloaded and executed (status file should show that but it doesn't)

Comment: Yes, i did check that and I can assure you that the script was not downloaded at all..
Is there a specific file you would like me to check?

Comment: I used Azure diag tool, and here what it says:

We ran diagnostics and found an issue
We found the following details of your deployment failure: the resource operation completed with terminal provisioning state
'failed'.. For general troubleshooting, use the following guides which cover the most common Azure deployment scenarios.
Recommended Steps
1. Identify the deployment error code using the Troubleshoot common Azure deployment errors guide
2. Troubleshoot deploying Windows Virtual Machines
3. Troubleshoot deploying Linux Virtual Machines

Comment: OK, I found the logs you are talking about. Here what it says:

Execution Error:
Unhandled Exception: System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException: The data contract type 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.GuestAgent.Plugins.CustomScriptHandler.ProtectedSettings' cannot be deserialized because the required data members 'storageAccountKey, storageAccountName' were not found.
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.GuestAgent.Plugins.CustomScriptHandler.Program.DeserializeJsonString[T](String jsonString, Encoding encoding) in

Comment: but this is strange, because MSFT says "managedIdentity property must not be used in conjunction with storageAccountName or storageAccountKey properties"

 https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/extensions/custom-script-windows#:~:text=Note-,managedIdentity%20property%20must%20not%20be%20used%20in%20conjunction%20with%20storageAccountName%20or%20storageAccountKey%20properties,-Template%20deployment

Comment: Your understanding is the same as mine, here's a sample I've been working with: https://gist.github.com/bmoore-msft/811cb09050896ebc15473bea8ccb481f - I don't see much difference between that and yours.  If that doesn't unblock you send me an email and I'll try to connect you with some folks.  (remove "-msft" from my username)

Comment: @WaleedSaifi - how did you resolve the issue?

Comment: After staring at the error for a while I noticed the issue was related to TLS, so i dropped down the TLS version on the Storage account from 1.2  to 1.0. that resolved it!